# How to view QJsonArray, QJsonValue value while debugging in Vistual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2019

How do I view QJsonArray, QJsonObject or QJsonValue while debugging. I have installed the QT plugin, and can see the QString value, but wanted to see the other object values as well, without modifying the code.

Comment: You can read this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2019 . It describes how to write custom visualizers for Visual Studio. You can try to write one for `QJson*` types.